# Python numpy fill masked elements in matrix according to order in another matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to do a Uniform Order Crossover for a genetic algorithm. In that, I have two 2D arrays p1 and p2 and a 2D bit array, b. p1, p2 and b are of the same shape. I mask elements in p1 corresponding to 1s in b and elements in p2 corresponding to 0s in b. From these, I need to generate 2 matrices c1 and c2 such that c1 has the same elements as in p2 but has the blanks replaced by the corresponding values in p2 as per the order given in p1 and the opposite for c1.

For example:

```
p1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]]
p2 = [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
      [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]]
b = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

masked arrays are mp1 and mp2;

```
mp1 = [[1, _, 3, _, 5],
       [1, _, _, 2, _]]
mp2 = [[_, 4, _, 2, _],
       [_, 1, 3, _, 5]]
```

Then c1 and c2 would be,

```
c1 = [[1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
      [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]]
c2 = [[1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
      [4, 1, 3, 2, 5]]
```

p1, p2, b, c1, c2 are of dimension 500X100000 in my case, so the answer needs to be vectorized and efficient.

Comment: I'm currently doing:

    c1, c2 = p2.copy, p1.copy

and then:

    for index in range(c1.shape[0]):
        c1[index][~b[index]] = p1[index][np.in1d(p1[index], p2[index][~b]]
but that modifies a copy of c1 and not c1 directly so I'm going nowhere with it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly make sense of what exactly you're asking, because either you have made a typo in your question or I'm just completely missing the point here.

So, first we have a mask for p1

```
mp1 = [[1, _, 3, _, 5],
       [1, _, _, 2, _]]
```

where the `_` values should be replaced by corresponding values from p2. Which should be

```
[[_, 4, _, 2, _],
 [_, 1, 3, _, 5]]
```

so in my head the result should be

```
[[1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
 [1, 1, 3, 2, 5]])
```

but you say the expected result is

```
[[1, 4, 3, 2, 5],
 [1, 3, 4, 2, 5]]
```

how does 3 appear there and where does the 4 come from? What am I missing? (Before anyone holds this against me, I can't fit this in a comment)

If you can use `numpy`, and for stuff like this I recommend you do, the solution, to the best of my interpretation abilities, would be:

```
p1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]]
p2 = [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
      [2, 1, 3, 4, 5]]
b = [[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

#this is just how you turn python lists into numpy arrays
import numpy as np
p1 = np.asarray(p1)
p2 = np.asarray(p2)
b = np.asarray(b)

#this is the actual solution to the problem
p1[b==0] = p2[b==0]
```

These substitutions are done in place, so it's nice for the memory and they're basically done in the background in C which means it's lightning fast.

Comment: Think of it this way. c2 contains the exact same elements that p1 has, but in a different order, and c1 has the exact same elements as p2 has but in a different order. The order is given by the other matrix. Each row is basically a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 5. That property has to hold true for the children too. There cannot be repetitions. All that I'm copying from the other matrix is the order in which they exist.

Comment: Let's do it for a single row. p1 is 52341, p2 is 31254, b is 10101. To make c1, take p2*b1 which gives 30204. The zeros need to be filled now. Since each row has to contain the same elements from the parent, c1 has to have all elements from p2, but the order has to be the order in which they appeared in p1. The missing elements are 1 and 5. Their order in p1 is 5,1. So fill the zeros in that order, 5 for first zero, 1 for the second. So c1 becomes 35214. Notice that it has the same elements that p2 had, and that 3, 2, 4 are in the same place and order as in p2. 1, 5 are filled in by p1s order

Comment: I am using numpy. I would hopefully like the solution to use numpy array functions only.